# Какие преимущества SSD перед HDD для Rails проекта (включая PostgreSQL)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, веб-сервер

Сейчас проект размещается на сервере с SSD. На этом сервере размещен как проект, так и БД.

В планах переезд на новый хостинг, где все планирую развернуть на двух серверах:

1. Сервер задач и БД - будет размещена БД, а также Rails задачи для обслуживания проекта (включая парсеры с записью в БД).
2. Сервер Rails проекта - чисто сервер под проект и его кэширование.

Хостинг предоставляет VPS на виртуализации KVM в двух конфигурациях:

1. HDD + SSD (скорее всего SSD кэширование).
2. SSD.

Сейчас я склонен к первому варианту - HDD + SSD, так как не вижу смысла в переплате за чистый SSD. Базе данных и Rails задачам уж точно не нужен SSD и им отлично подойдет простой связки HDD + SSD. Что касается сервера проекта, то тут тоже особо не вижу смысла.

Правильно ли я мыслю?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если честно, не очень понятно, чем обусловлен переезд и экономия на ssd, если хватает на два сервера. В общем случае остается только порекомендовать не слезать с SSD, если позволяют финансовые возможности.

> Базе данных и Rails задачам уж точно не нужен SSD и им отлично подойдет простой связки HDD + SSD. Что касается сервера проекта, то тут тоже особо не вижу смысла.

В сравнении hdd/ssd принято различать последовательный и случайный доступ. На самом деле это два крайних случая, которые в реальности будут смешаны в разной пропорции, но можно говорить о "более последовательном" и "более случайном" доступе к данным. База данных, в общем случае, является источником "более случайного" доступа к данным (насколько понимаю, последовательным чтением может быть только table scan, от которого всегда стараются избавиться с помощью index scan), и именно случайный доступ к данным является одной из killer feature ssd - разница во времени случайного доступа может составлять два порядка по сравнению с сферически-вакуумным hdd. Поэтому в общем случае я бы рекомендовал БД остаться на SSD. Приложение скорее всего никак не использует диск кроме начальной загрузки и записи логов, и в этом случае скорость диска будет совсем некритичной.

Тем не менее, это все рекомендации для общего случая. Ядро linux, файловая система и сам диск имеют кэш для горячих данных, и если вся ваша БД в него умещается, а записей в секунду не так уж и много, вы можете и не заметить разницы. Если быть до конца честным, от смены серверов меняется слишком много переменных, чтобы что-то утверждать, но в общем случае вы скорее всего заметите падение перформанса на всех использующих диск приложениях в зависимости от генерируемой ими нагрузки на диск; больше всего - от базы данных. Если у вас не сильно нагруженный проект и скорость загрузки страницы достаточно мала, чтобы ее полуторное (сферически-вакуумное полуторное) увеличение не ощущалось пользователями - все должно быть ок и на сетапе без ssd.

Если же вдруг вы по каким-то причинам хотите устраивать файл подкачки на диске, то в этом случае не использовать SSD становится просто криминально.

Что такое связка HDD + SSD - мне непонятно, если это просто два примонтированных в разные точки жестких диска, то тогда можно разместить базу данных на SSD и особо не волноваться.

Answer (score 1):

> Правильно ли я мыслю?

Не совсем правильно, ибо критерии `"подойдет"`/`"не подойдет"` - не определены. И второй момент - совсем не ясно как будет использоваться `SSD/HDD` + `RAM`. Это от многого зависит, и от размера БД, и от самих запросов, от характера использования программного кэша БД, и еще ряда моментов.

В таких условиях, можно с уверенностью сказать одно, что вариант с `SSD` будет не хуже `SSD+HDD`. А вот на сколько может быть лучше, можно только гадать.

Я бы поступил следующим образом:

- взял бы на месяц тариф с `SSD`, за это время определил бы средние скоростные работы характеристики установленного софта
- спустя месяц бы перешел на тариф "ниже", провел бы те же замеры
- по результатам сравнения принимал бы решение, если второй вариант - не устраивает, и хотелось бы лучшего (и готовность за это платить), вернулся бы на "дорогой" тарифный план